# Form submitting inside an iFrame loads in the same iframe and not in a subiframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, target

I created a script that submits a form to an iFrame (download.php):

```php
<?php 
//Download.php
echo '<form id="secret" action="http://location.com" target="hidden" method="post">
<!--- There are some input hiddens -->
</form>';
echo '<iframe name="hidden"></iframe>';
echo "<script>
     window.onload = function() {
         secretsend();
         var form = document.getElementById('secret');
         form.onsubmit = function() {
              alert('TEST2');
         }
     }


     function parentsub() 
     {
         parent.document.getElementById('google').submit();
     }
     function secretsend() 
     {
         alert('TEST');
         document.getElementById('secret').submit();
     }
</script>";
?>
```

That works, but when `secretsend()` is loaded the form submits it to the main page (that is an iFrame, as I said before) and not to `hidden` iFrame, (the initial form changes its src to http://location.com/, the action url of the form)... How can I solve that issue?

I need that for call another function called `parentsub()` but if the main content is replaced is impossible that anything can be called.

Comment: Strange, it should work.

Comment: I don't know. What if you put a submit button in the form in order to test if it will submit to the iframe?

Comment: I added a submit button and it works inside the iFrame... But for some reason with javascript onsubmit value is refused, maybe because I have to use javascript instead for that attribute...

Comment: This happends in all browsers?

Comment: Yes...

With that doesn't work either:

`window.onload = function() {
 secretsend();
    var form = document.getElementById('secret');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        alert('TEST2');
    }
}`

Comment: Well I made a little changes in the code, for know what exactly I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using This code.

```
echo '<form id="secret" action="http://location.com" target="_self" method="post">
```

Target:  `_self` attribute opens the linked document in same frame.